# WP: How to create a custome UI pivot?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to creat a page in pivot control. It looks like the photo (I designed in photoshop):

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HL07lVgHwx8/UTXxttNXk0I/AAAAAAAAAHs/93Gj3bw1-q0/s427/DSPhong.PNG

The question: How to design the UI look like the photo by using XAML, blend 4 or C# code??

Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't see what's so custom about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much do you know about [DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx)? What you need to do is following:

- Change background image, either Pivot.Background or Page.Background
- Design data templates as grid with three lines and three columns. This step is easy, but you need to learn how to use DataTemplates.

Experiment first.

Comment: Thank Toni Petrinaso much!